# Node Socket.io client thinks it is disconnected after it has connected

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

My socket will connect but can't receive messages in either direction. I set up the logging shown below. On the server side I see connections being logged, and disconnections logged when the page is closed. If I kill the server, the client logs "Socket disconnected." But no emissions going either direction are received. I did some more logging and determined that the client socket's `socket.connected` field is `false`.

At this point I'm at a total loss. Literally as soon as I make a connection, the client thinks that its socket is disconnected, but the server still sees it disconnect when I close the browser window. I'm running socket.io 1.1.0. Thanks for any help!

Server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  logger.info('Socket connected. ID: ' + socket.id);

  socket.on('refresh', function() { 
    logger.info('Refresh received from ID: ' + socket.id);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function() { 
    logger.info('Disconnect received from ID: ' socket.id);
  });
});
```

Client:

```
var socket;
$(document).ready(function() {
  socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  console.log(socket.connected);

  socket.emit('refresh');

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("Socket disconnected.");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was with `socket = io.connect(document.URL);` I tried using the socket.io autodiscover via `socket = io();` and now all of my emissions are working just fine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate which version made it work?

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer yikes i have no idea, this was 3 years ago for a hobby project that i haven't touched in ages. my package.json just sets socket.io to 'latest' -- so whatever version was up-to-date in October 2014... Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

The socket is not immediately connected after the `io.connect`. You have to wait:

```
var socket;
$(document).ready(function() {
  socket = io.connect('http://localhost');


  socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log(socket.connected);
    socket.emit('refresh');
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("Socket disconnected.");
  });
});
```

More events: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object)

Comment: When I `console.log` inside `socket.on('connect', fn() {});` I never see anything get logged. I also added a `socket.emit` on the server side inside the callback for `io.sockets.on('connect')` which must wait until after the connection is complete, and that is not received by the client either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reconnect after being disconnected automatically

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
   console.log("Socket disconnected.");
   socket.socket.reconnect();
});
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't appear to be disconnected yet. When I call `socket = io.connect('http://localhost');` I see a connection created message logged by the server, but the client's socket object says it is not connected. But when I close the browser window, the server logs a socket disconnection message, implying that the client socket was in fact connected, and sent a disconnect message.